# How best to create a Windows 8 Metro Hub Page

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I want to create a Windows 8 Metro application that has a fancy "hub" page similar to the following:

http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-51-31-metablogapi/3482.landing_2D00_branded_5F00_thumb_5F00_287109A4.jpg

The key elements are: Horizontal Panorama style scrolling page but with "sections" that are data bound.  I've had a look around for implementations and have come up short.

Seems to me it would be possible to do with a ScrollViewer that contains a Horizontal Stackpanel that has the elements that make up each section.  But seeing as this is such a common Metro design pattern, I figure there is probably an easier / recommended way of implementing.

Just wondering if someone can give me some tips.  How would you do it?

Comment: Yah, it is the built-in Grid Application project template.

Comment: Really? You can have the various "sections" that have different layouts within the Grid Application Project Template?  I figured, this would allow the grid elements but didn't realise it would handle the other panel type formats in the linked image.

Answer (score 1):

When you start using VariableSizedWrapGrid all things get their own relative sizes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227651.aspx

Set the ColumnSpan and RowSpan properties to make things double size, tripple size etc...

For me I make the first item in the collection double width, double height by setting ColumnSpan and RowSpan to 2. All other items get this ColumnSpan and Rowspan to 1, and it's getting a nice effect.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what Hans mentioned, I would highly recommend going through the existing [Metro Style App Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/site/search). Learning from working examples works better than any documentation.